# Key and value avro messages distribution in Kafka topic partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We use kafka topic with 6 partitions and the incoming messages from producers have 4 keys key1,key2,key3,key4 and their corresponding values, I see that the values are distributed only with 3 partitions and the remaining partitions remains empty.

1. Is the distribution of the messages based n the hash values of the key?
2. Let is say my hash value of Key1 is XXXX, to which partition does it go among the total of 6 partitions?
3. I am using kafka connect HDFS connector to write the data to HDFS, and I knew  that it uses the hash values of the keys to distribute to the messages   to the partitions,is it the same way kafka uses to distribute the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, the distribution of messages against partitions is determined by hash of the message-key modulo total partition count on that topic. E.g. if you're sending a message *m* with key as *k*, to a topic *mytopic* that has *p* partitions, then *m* goes to the partition *k*.hashCode() % *p* in *mytopic*. I think that answers your second question too. In your case two of the resulting values are getting mapped to same partition.
- If my memory serves me correctly Kafka-hdfs connector should take care of consuming from a Kafka topic and putting it into Hadoop HDFS. You don't need to worry about the partitions there, it is abstracted out.

Comment: Thank you!! can we override this behavior of using key to distribute the value to all the partitions

Comment: Yes you can write your own partitioner class and pass it in your Kafka producer using the *partitioner.class* properties. You can find the default implementation in *org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner* class.